# Why I got this error: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, frontend

I'm new at programming and also in React. I'm trying to start my project, but it doesn't start.
Here is the error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-10T04_38_38_989Z-debug.log
```

Here is log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~prestart: client@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: client@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\ReactProjects\restaurant-app\client\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64;C:\Program Files\wget;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
9 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: CWD: D:\ReactProjects\restaurant-app\client
10 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:321:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid client@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\ReactProjects\restaurant-app\client
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

P.S. I tried out to clean cache, delete node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstall them, but it didn't fix my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Sorry for my stupidity. I just moved  my "public" folder into components.
Moved up into root folder and project launched.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you can try to remove node_modules and reinstall all them with the command 'npm install' or 'yarn'

Comment: have you install nodejs and npm previously ?
are you use create-react-app ?

Comment: Yes. I have it.

Comment: that doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Use the **CDN** links of **Bootstrap** .
Get started with [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: Try to reinstall your react project in another directory after updating npm & yarn

Answer (score 0):

I did have same issues but I had to delete package-lock.json
And node_modules folder and Problem gone immediately

But remember to check if cache is cleaned or clean it by forcing it
Like this

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Again run `npm install` command so as to re-install properly deleted modules

Happy coding @Ykee